# Android podcast player app, google play rejected for Voice commands

Tags: android, google-play

Your app does not support all of the required voice commands. You can read more about how to support Voice Actions in the Android Developers Help Center.[image]

How can I fix this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a customer service question, only programming questions are allowed in SO regardless if Google accept or reject the app you submitted. See also [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw that there are more people with this problem see here: https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-Android/issues/6124.

1) If it was me I would look at this link from android: https://developer.android.com/training/auto/audio/index.html#support_voice and then implement the voice commands in my app. So follow the instructions by setting it up in your manifest file and then add the commands in code. I should not take that long and try again.

2)If that does not work I would contact the the google play store to find out what else you should do.